# Cannot set property with previously defined property in botbnt framework composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am working on a bot build with Microsoft bot framework composer

I have an HTTP request that works and returns an array of programs

Currently, I have a "0" hard set and that works
`${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[0].name}`

what i am trying to do is take property called `dialog.resultnumber` which is set to `0` and replace static "0" above with property called `dialog.resultsnumber`

I tried:

```
${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[${dialog.resultsnumber}].name}
${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[(dialog.resultsnumber)].name}
${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[dialog.resultsnumber].name}
${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[getproperty(dialog.resultsnumber)].name}
${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[dialog.resultsnumber()].name}
${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[${dialog.resultsnumber()}].name}
```

I cannot find the syntax to use an already defined property to build a new property

Answer (score 0):

> what i am trying to do is take property called dialog.resultnumber which is set to 0 and replace static "0" above with property called dialog.resultsnumber I tried:

Are you sure that `dialog.resultsnumber` is an int?

If you set it in a single set property action, make sure you set it as an int, the default is a string.

[image: How to set property to integer type]

This below should be the one. It worked for me (with the above caveat):
`${dialog.programlistlite.api_response.content.programs[dialog.resultsnumber].name}`

You can also use the [isInteger()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#isInteger) type checking function to confirm if something is an int, or try and force/convert/coerce using [int()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#int) if needed as well.